Are two-periodic two-generated ideals of Gorenstein local domains self-dual?
Let $I$ be a non-principal ideal of a Gorenstein local domain $R$ such that there is an exact sequence $0\to I \to R^{\oplus 2}\to R^{\oplus 2}\to I\to 0$.
Then, must it be true that $I\cong \text{Hom}_R(I, R)$?
Thoughts: Since $I$ is two-periodic and $R$ is Gorenstein, hence $I$ is a maximal Cohen-Macaulay $R$-module, and so is $\text{Hom}_R(I, R)$. This implies $I$ is reflexive and $\text{Ext}_R^{>0}(I\oplus \text{Hom}_R(I, R), R)=0$. Clearly from this, we get an exact sequence $$0\to \text{Hom}_R(I,R) \to R^{\oplus 2}\to R^{\oplus 2}\to \text{Hom}_R(I,R) \to 0$$
... I'm not sure where to go from here ... please help.
